# Using typescript class-validator for (nested) index signature

Tags: typescript, class-validator

I would like to validate (using `class-validator`) a class having an index signature:

```js
class Example {
  myProp: { [foo: string]: string }
}
```

I would like to make sure the myProp.something and myProp.somethingElse are actually strings, not number, objects, arrays, ...

Any idea how to do this?

One approach was to use a separate class an `IsString()` like this:

```js
class MyProp {
  @IsString()
  [foo: string]: string
}

class Example {
  @IsDefined()
  @ValidateNested()
  myProp: MyProp
}
```

However, typescript won't compile: `Decorators are not valid here.`

Actually I would also like to validate types like `{ [foo: string]: { [bar: string]: string } }`. But let's start with the easier example first ;-)

Comment: The snippet you have ensures that `myProp.something` is contains a string type, so what are you asking here? Providing a simple example would clarify greatly.

Comment: Did you try `@IsString()`? I guess you'd want to make a separate class for the decorators

Comment: Just to clarify, decorators can only be added to classes I think, so `myProp` would need to store a class, not an interface like you have it

Comment: I tried `@IsString()` in a separate class. I get the error "Decorators are not valid here." :-(

Comment: Can you share your attempt?

Comment: Sure, please find it above.

Answer (score 2):

Since decorators cannot be attached to index signatures (which do not exist at runtime), [you can alternatively use a Map](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator/issues/795) for the simple case.

```js
class Example {
    @IsInstance(Map)
    @IsString({ each: true })
    myProp: Map<string, string>;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. However, I don't consider this a solution to the problem, but a different problem ;-)
I want to validate an incoming object. Your answer validates a different object, so I would first have to transform the object. Transforming an object only to validate it (and then transform it back) doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: You have to transform it no matter what, [per the documentation](https://github.com/typestack/class-validator#validating-plain-objects). But more to the point, `class-validator` doesn't have the functionality you want, so the only thing that can be done is propose alternatives.